# I am trying to make an if statement where it looks if the Edittext(number) is greater than an int value but it doesn't work

Tags: java, android, if-statement

When I try to check if the input from the edittext( number) is less than the int value, it says that I can't compare an < to an EditText. My value is an int and the input is for numbers and, how I understand is, an int is a number. So, why can't I compare them? (If this is easy to solve, I have to say I am a beginner in Android Development)

Code:

```
package com.teamtreehouse.airport;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AirPortActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText nameTextView;
    private  EditText inputNumberAge;

    private Button nextActivityButton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_air_port);

        nameTextView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nameeditText);
        inputNumberAge = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputNumberAge);






        nextActivityButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextActivityButton);

        nextActivityButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Integer.parseInt(inputNumberAge.getText().toString()));
                String nameOfUser = nameTextView.getText().toString();
                int numberAge = 18;

                if (inputNumberAge > numberAge) {
                    Toast.makeText(AirPortActivity.this, "No Permission yet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                else




                startStory();
                String nameOfUserToast = "Hi " + nameOfUser;
                Toast.makeText(AirPortActivity.this, nameOfUserToast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });


    }

    private void startStory() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AirPortSetup.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must assign the parsed value to an int var and then compare that var like this:

```
int parsedInt = Integer.parseInt(inputNumberAge.getText().toString()));

...

if (parsedInt > numberAge) {
```

Integer.parseInt() returns a value, but if you don't assign that value to anything you are parsing and wasting your result data. Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that you are comparing incompatable types in your if statement. `numberAge` is an `int`, while `inputNumberAge` is an `EditText`. You create an `Integer` value from `inputNumberAge` in this line

```
    Integer.parseInt(inputNumberAge.getText().toString()));
```

However, you are not assigning this value to a variable and are not using this value in the if statement. Try these changes to the line above and to the if statement

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    int inputAge = Integer.parseInt(inputNumberAge.getText().toString()));
    String nameOfUser = nameTextView.getText().toString();
    int numberAge = 18;

    if (inputAge > numberAge) {
```

This will take the `Integer` value of `inputNumberAge` and assign it to a variable named `inputAge`. The if statement will then compare this int value to the `numberAge` value.

Please let me know if this helps, or if you need any further clarification.

Answer (score 1):

you need to store the number in integer variable and use try and catch to check if user enter interger or not

```
        int val;
         try
            {
               val = Integer.parseInt(inputNumberAge.getText().toString()));            
            }catch (IOException e)
            {
               Toast.makeText(AirPortActivity.this, "Only integer value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

             String nameOfUser = nameTextView.getText().toString();
             int numberAge = 18;

             if (val> numberAge) {
                   Toast.makeText(AirPortActivity.this, "No Permission yet!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
```